# 10 digit numbers starting with 4 or 6

Tags: r, regex

In R I would like the code to find numbers starting with 4 or 6 in numbers with 10 digits.

This works to get the 10 digit numbers:

```
grep("^[[:digit:]]{10}$"
```

This doesn't work to get them starting with 4 or 6:

```
grep([46]\"^[[:digit:]]{10}$"
```

Examples

```
x <- c("4303669792", "6200406014")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
grep("^[46][0-9]{9}$", x)
       ^^^^      ^
```

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `[46]` - `4` or `6`
- `[0-9]{9}` - nine digits
- `$` - end of string.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/98fpTO/1) and a [Regulex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E%5B46%5D%5B0-9%5D%7B9%7D%24):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple math as well, i.e.

```
x <- c('4982748923', '6165751984', '31094583285')

as.numeric(x) %/% 1000000000 %in% c(4, 6)
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `grepl` and `nchar`

```
grepl("^[4|6]", x) & nchar(x) == 10
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

With `grepl` find if string starts with "4" or "6" and check if number of characters in it is equal to 10.

If you need the values, subset it

```
x[grepl("^[4|6]", x) & nchar(x) == 10]
#[1] "4982748923" "6165751984"
```

**data**

```
x <- c('4982748923', '6165751984', '31094583285', '654')
```